# Case statement to generate two values in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

i have a table Periods

```
Periods
presentday
presentday+1
presentday+2
presentday+3
Presenday
presentday+1
presentday+2
presentday+3
```

My Query to get case when periods=Present Day

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-') as StartDate
 ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-') as EndDate
from Periods where Periods='Presentday'
```

How can i write a case statement for above query??

Comment: CASE statement to do what?

Comment: `How can i write a case statement for above query` Why do you even need a case statement for the posted query?

Comment: CASE statement to do what? What is your desired output?

Comment: @M.Ali  Actually i am writing a Stored Proc where it will checks the every row in Periods table and get startdate and Enddate.

Comment: @Rahul Actually i am writing a Stored Proc where it will checks the every row in Periods table and get startdate and Enddate.

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes and imagine if someone showed you this data and asked the question you are asking will you be able to understand the question? StartDate and enddate of what?

Comment: @M.Ali i have completed my query only for present day if you execute it you can see StartDate and Enddate.

Comment: So you want to be able to add one to current date when it says presentday+1 , 2 when its presentday+2 and so on... ?

Comment: @M.Ali:I can generate that code.My question how can i use case statement for that to check Period type and generate startdate and Enddate?

Comment: Start date and end date of what ????????

Comment: @M.Ali: For periodtype.

Comment: @M.Ali:End date will todaydate but start date will ne depends on period type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I can think of to try and make sense out of the question.

```
create table Periods(Period varchar(30))
insert Periods
select 'presentday' union 
select 'presentday+1' union 
select 'presentday+2' union 
select 'presentday+3'

select p.Period,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-') as StartDate,
        case when p.Period = 'presentday' then REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-')
            when p.Period = 'presentday+1' then REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, dateadd(d,1,getdate()), 113),1,11),' ','-')
            when p.Period = 'presentday+2' then REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, dateadd(d,2,getdate()), 113),1,11),' ','-')
            when p.Period = 'presentday+3' then REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, dateadd(d,3,getdate()), 113),1,11),' ','-') end as EndDate

from Periods p
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's some number you can get from the Periods table reliably, this is more dynamic:

```
select p.Period,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-') as StartDate,
        case
            when p.Period = 'presentday' then REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, getdate(), 113),1,11),' ','-')
            else REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, dateadd(d,cast(right(p.Period,1) as int),getdate()), 113),1,11),' ','-')
        end
from periods p
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Y' to data type int.